# Why Vue.js image component is doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vue-component

I have something problem.
I wanna make a Vue.js Component.
this component show something image.
it similar  `<img>`tag.If you know `<img>`tag, You can understand very easy to this question.

So I want make Vue component like this.
my code is following below

```
  props: ['link,des'],
template: '<img :src={{ link }} :alt={{ des }}></img>'
}),
```

this code is javascipt

html code is following below

```
  <image link="https://kr.vuejs.org/images/logo.png" des="sans"></image>
```

pls answer me kindly.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't use the reserved keyword (`image`) as a component. Then you don't need to use curly brackets for the HTML attributes. Here is the working example.

```js
Vue.component('my-image', {
  props: ['link', 'des'],
  template: `<img :src='link' :alt='des'></img>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<my-image id='app' link="https://kr.vuejs.org/images/logo.png" des="sans"></my-image>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

Your property `props` is wrongly set. You need to split your string.

```
props: ['link', 'des'],
```

There is several way to do this. You can even specify the type of your props :

```
props: {
    link: String, 
    des: String
},
```

All details can be found in the documentation here : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Types

Comment: Thank you for answer